# Minimum storage space for an ordered list

Tags: list, storage

I am seeking advice on achieving the most efficient storage of an ordered list, that is the minimum storage for a list.

An ordered list of 256 unique items where each item is a unique number from 0 to 255 will standardly require 2^16 bits of data for storage, 2^8 places, each place holding a 2^8 value.

However this information ought to be storable in near 2^15 bits.

The second item, rather than being in the 2nd place of 256, can be viewed as being the next of the remaining 255, the next item the next of the remaining 254 etc.

This is a continuation of not needing to store the detail of the last item in a sorted list because that item must be in the last place by default.

In this case you can simply see you can have 2^8-1 places each place holding a 2^8 value, which is less than 2^16.

So how does this get down to 2^15+1 bits of storage.  Or is there a proof that says otherwise?  If there is a proof I would hope it doesn't say 2^16 bits of storage are needed as I have just shown that that is wrong!

I am hopefully just unaware of the terminology to identify work on  this subject.

Can anyone advise of work on the matter?

Thank you for your time.

Glenn

Comment: Pigeonhole analogy is not quite right as, as stated, there is definitely sufficient information to not include the last item, so get away with 255 pigeon holes rather than 256.  So any existing proof of pigeonhole theory is wrong if it "proves" 256 pigeonholes are required.  So is anyone aware of any proofs that prove the pigeonhole theory is wrong? thanks for your time - Glenn

Comment: A misunderstanding here, I use the term 'ordered list' to mean order matters, a permutation rather a combination where order does not matter.  This seems to be different from your interpretation of "ordered list" being some calculable known process such as all values increasing.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Upon clarification of the question as storage of some particular permutation of 256 items (being the 8-bit numbers from 0 to 255 in particular), I have updated my answer. The prior discussion is below for posterity.

**Answer**

1684 bits.

**Explanation**

In this case, the clearest analysis comes through encoding and informational entropy. Again, we use the pigeonhole principle: in order to uniquely determine a particular permutation, we must have at least as many encodings as we have possible messages to be encoded.

An example may be helpful: consider a list of 256 numbers, each of which is an 8-bit number. The first item has 256 possible values, as does the second, as does the third, and so on. Overall, we have 256^256 possible messages, so we need at least 256^256 possible encodings. To determine the number of bits needed, we can simply take the base 2 logarithm of this, and log2(256^256) = 256*log2(256) = 256 * log2(2^8) = 256 * 8 = 2^11, so we can see that to encode this list, we only need 2^11, or 2048 bits. You may note this is the same as taking 8 bits per item, and multiplying it by the number of items. Your original question was incorrect on the storage needed, as you supposed that it requires 2^8 bits, so a 256 bit integer, which could store values from 0 to ~10^77.

With this understanding, we turn our attention to the problem at hand. There are 256 possibilities for the first item, then 255 possibilities for the second item, 254 possibilities for the third item, etc, until there is only 1 possibility for the last item. Overall, we have 256! possibilities, so we need at least 256! encodings. Again, we use the base 2 logarithm to determine how many bits we need, so we need log2(256!) bits. A nice property of logarithms is that they turn products into sums, so log2(256!) = log2(256) + log2(255) + log2(254) + ... + log2(2) + log2(1). This is analogous to using 8 bits for each of the 256 items, but here as each item has progressively less information, it requires fewer bits. Also note that log2(1) is 0, which corresponds to your observation that you don't need any information to encode the last item. Overall, when we perform this sum, we end up with 1683.996..., so we need 1684 bits to encode these ordered lists. Some variable-length encodings could get lower, but they can never go lower than log2(256!) bits on average.

Coming up with an encoding that uses 1684 bits is not simple, but here's one method that's more efficient than the original full storage. We can note that the first 128 items each have between 129 and 256 possibilities, and encode each of these items with 8 bits. The next 64 items each have between 65 and 128 possibilities, so we can encode each of these items with 7 bits. Continuing on, we end up using
(128 * 8) + (64 * 7) + (32 * 6) + (16 * 5) + (8 * 4) + (4 * 3) + (2 * 2) + (1 * 1) + (1 * 0) = 1793 bits to store the list.

---

**Pre-clarification discussion**

If all you're ever interested in encoding is an ordered list of 256 unique items, where each item is an 8-bit integer, then you can do it in 1 bit: 0 means you have that list, 1 means you don't, because there's only one possible list satisfying those criteria.

If you're trying to store anything in memory, you need at least as many configurations of that memory as there are different options (otherwise by the pigeonhole principle there would be at least two options you couldn't differentiate). Assuming by "ordered" you mean that they are strictly increasing or decreasing, an n-element ordered list of 8-bit integers, without repetition, has 256 choose n possible options (as there's only one possible configuration, the ordered one). Summing 256 choose n over all possible values of n (i.e. 0 to 256), gives 2^256, or 2^(2^8). Therefore, a perfect encoding scheme could use as few as 2^8 bits to store this particular kind of list, but couldn't encode any other kind of list.

EDIT: If you want to read more about this sort of stuff, read up on information theory.

EDIT: An easier way to think about this encoding is like this: We know the list is ordered, so if we know what items are in it then we know what order they're in, so we only need to know which items are in the list. There's 256 possible items (0 through 255), and if we assume the items in the list are unique then each item is either in the list, or it isn't. For each item, we use 1 bit to store whether or not it's in the list (so bit 0 records if the list contains 0, bit 1 records if the list contains 1, etc, bit 255 records if the list contains 255). Tada, we've stored all of the information about this 256 element array of bytes in only 256 = 2^8 bits.

EDIT: Let's examine an analogous situation. We have an ordered, unique list of up to 4 items, each of which is 2 bits. We'll write out all of the possible circumstances:[], [0], [1], [2], [3], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [0,1,2], [0,1,3], [0,2,3], [1,2,3], [0,1,2,3]. These are the *only* possible lists where each element is two bits, the elements are unique, and the elements are in ascending order. Notice that I can't actually make it more efficient just by leaving the 3 off of [0,1,2,3], because I also need to distinguish it from [0,1,2]. The thing is, asking how much space you need to "store" something isolated from context is almost unanswerable. If all you want is to store enough information to recover it (i.e. you want lossless compression), and if you presume you know the properties, you can get your compression ratio pretty much as low as you want. For example, if you gave me an ordered list containing every element from 0 to 1,000,000 exactly once, even though storing that list directly in memory requires ~2^40 bits, you can recover the list from the known properties and the two numbers 0 and 1,000,000, for a total of 40 bits.